# Unable to change font color in segmentedControl

Tags: objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol, textcolor

I am using the code below to set the text color in my segmented control. However, it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing out something here?

```
// Set up segment control
NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Popular", @"Starred", nil];
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(40, 200, 220, 20);
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;

self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl;

for (id segment in [segmentedControl subviews])
{
    for (id label in [segment subviews])
    {
        if ([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
            [label setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
            [label setColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        }
    }           
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting iOS 5+ then you should do it like this:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17], UITextAttributeFont,
                        [UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                        nil];
[_segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
NSDictionary *highlightedAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
[_segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:highlightedAttributes forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```